# TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

I try to authentificate to connect to Google API in order to use Google Analytics. Here is my code:

```
'use strict'


const fs = require('fs')
const open = require('open')
const Fs = require('fs')
const Google = require('googleapis')
const Url = require('url')
const Http = require('http')


const CREDENTIALS_DIR = './.credentials/'
const SECRET_PATH = CREDENTIALS_DIR + 'google-analytics-secret.json'
const TOKEN_PATH = CREDENTIALS_DIR + 'google-analytics-accesstoken.json'


let auth = loadCredentials()
const oauth2Client = new Google.auth.OAuth2(
  auth.CLIENT_ID,
  auth.CLIENT_SECRET,
  auth.REDIRECT_URL)

function loadCredentials () {

  try {
    let secret = Fs.readFileSync(SECRET_PATH)
    console.log('Credentials successfully loaded from file.')
    return {
      CLIENT_ID: JSON.parse(secret).web.client_id,
      CLIENT_SECRET: JSON.parse(secret).web.client_secret,
      REDIRECT_URL: JSON.parse(secret).web.redirect_uris[0]
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    if (err.code !== 'ENOENT') {
      throw err
    }
    else {
      console.log('Credentials successfully loaded from environment.')
      return {
        CLIENT_ID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        CLIENT_SECRET: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        REDIRECT_URL: 'http://localhost:1234/'
      }
    }
  }
}

function getScopes () {

  return [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
  ]
}


function getAuthCallbackServer () {

  let url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: getScopes()
  })

  open(url, 'chrome')

  let server = Http.createServer(handleAuthCallback)

  server.listen(9999, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on: http://localhost:1234')
  })
}


// Parse Code sent by Google
function handleAuthCallback (req, res) {

  let parse = Url.parse(req.url)
  let code = parse.query.split('=').pop()
  console.log(`Got code: ${code}`)

  res.writeHead(200)
  res.end('Awesome... Got the Code')

}

getAuthCallbackServer()
```

I try to make it modular with the use of functions and I get the following error (inside the handleAuthCallback function) :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null
```

This is the object I got when I try to print `parse` in the handleAuthCallback function:

```
Url {
protocol: null,
slashes: null,
auth: null,
host: null,
port: null,
hostname: null,
hash: null,
search: '?code=x/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
query: 'code=x/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
pathname: '/',
path: '/?code=x/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
href: '/?code=x/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' }
```

I don't really understand this error as it was working before I refactored my code. Any advice on where I could be wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to print `parse` and `parse.query` to verify that it is indeed `null` and then fix it from there? Perhaps `req.url` is not what you're expecting (and there's no query)?

Comment: I think `parse` is code line  `let code = parse.query.split('=').pop()`  is a string so it does not have a `query` property. So did you check that?

Comment: Yes. The "query" key contains the code and it prints the code with the line "Got Code: ${code} before I get the error

Comment: Sorry, but if it prints the code before you get the error, then probably you have an error at another line, check it please. Because your console can not print smth after error.

Comment: The script prints the line `Credentials successfully loaded from file.`, `Created auth URL.`, `Server listening on: http://localhost:1234/`, `Got code: x/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` then throw me an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `query` is object, try this:

```
let parse = Url.parse(req.url);
let code = parse.query.code;
```

Comment: This is the object I get when I print `parse` which is equal to `Url.parse(req.url)` : `Url {
  protocol: null,
  slashes: null,
  auth: null,
  host: null,
  port: null,
  hostname: null,
  hash: null,
  search: '?code=x/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  query: 'code=x/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  pathname: '/',
  path: '/?code=x/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  href: '/?code=x/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' }`

Answer (score 0):

This `function` is being called:

```
// Parse Code sent by Google
function handleAuthCallback (req, res) {

  let parse = Url.parse(req.url)
  let code = parse.query.split('=').pop()
  console.log(`Got code: ${code}`)

  res.writeHead(200)
  res.end('Awesome... Got the Code')

}
```

when a callback occurs specified here:

```
let server = Http.createServer(handleAuthCallback)
```

`Url` is defined here:

```
const Url = require('url')
```

parse is the result of `Url.parse(req.url)`. This does not have a query property, so `parse.query` is `undefined` and therefore `parse.query.split` will yield error, it is possible that when you made some refactoring, the code which defined `query` was removed.

Comment: just after `let parse = Url.parse(req.url)` I added `console.log(parse.query.split('=').pop())` instead of `let code = parse.query.split('=').pop()` and console.log show the code. It also shows the code with `console.log('Got code: ${code}')` but give me an error just after